# Landing Page Image is not covering according to size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am Using Bootstrap studio and I have Used This code `backgroud-size:cover` it is working find in desktop mode but its not mobile friendly here are some screenshot

[Here's the Example In Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDuuH.png)
[Here's the Example In Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JDdG.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using:

```
background: no-repeat center center scroll;
```

Comment: Thanks For Replay (Instead Of Correcting Me .)